# How to Remember Combobox's Selected Value C# XAML Windows Phone8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

Now I'm making an app. and this app has Two Pages(Page1, Page2).

Page2 has Combobox. And Select Item.

Once I go back to Page1 And Go to Page2, Page2's Combobox Value resets to initial value.

I want to Page2's Combobox remember the "Selected ItemValue".

for example,

Page2 Combobox's Select Value is 1, 2(IsSelected), 3, 4.

And I Select "3". Next, Go Back to Page1

And Go Forward to Page2, Combobox's SelectedValue is "2" ("3" is good for me).

Please tell me how to do.

Comment: I can tell you at least 5 different ways to do it... which one do you want?

Comment: easy or normal one Please. thank you.

Comment: I wanna know how to save and load value of Combobox's value. Once App quit Combobox's value is initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I did it is with this line in your XAML file.

`NavigationCacheMode="Enabled"`

This will save the state when you navigate away from it.

Comment: Sorry, I added a question. About "How to Save and Load Combobox's value". I wanna know about this.